# Testing laravel uploaded project in local mode

Tags: php, laravel-5

I download a laravel project from host and i wanna test it in local mode.
Laravel folders are in a folder whose name is laravel. public contents and laravel are in system folder.
Now, project cannot find CSS and js files which are in system folder.
the address assigned :

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

how can i fix it ?

Comment: What is the generated HTML?

Comment: Have you cleared the config like - { php artisan config:clear }

Comment: no i did not clear config ...